# Perspective effect only working with unclosed img tags.. why? and how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create the exact effect below (but on a pop up modal). I got it to work so far but the html is broken (img tags not closed). And if I fix the img tags the perspective effect goes away. Can someone explain why and show me how to fix it please? I have perspective:100px on the main wrapper as per this article https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/..

```js
var lFollowX = 0,
    lFollowY = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    friction = 1 / 30;

function moveBackground() {
  x += (lFollowX - x) * friction;
  y += (lFollowY - y) * friction;
  
  translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px) scale(1.1)';

  $('.bg').css({
    '-webit-transform': translate,
    '-moz-transform': translate,
    'transform': translate
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {

  var lMouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
  var lMouseY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).height() / 2 - e.clientY));
  lFollowX = (20 * lMouseX) / 100; // 100 : 12 = lMouxeX : lFollow
  lFollowY = (10 * lMouseY) / 100;

});

moveBackground();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: #0F2044;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
          perspective: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap .bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  
  <div class="bg">
        <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/fg.svg"
  </div>
    <div class="bg">
        <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/mg.svg"
  </div>
      <div class="bg">
        <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/bg.svg" 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *invalid* code will create a nested elements of img that you can create like below:

```
<div class="bg">
    <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/fg.svg">
    <div class="bg">
      <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/mg.svg">
      <div class="bg">
        <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/bg.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
var lFollowX = 0,
  lFollowY = 0,
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  friction = 1 / 30;

function moveBackground() {
  x += (lFollowX - x) * friction;
  y += (lFollowY - y) * friction;

  translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px) scale(1.1)';

  $('.bg').css({
    '-webit-transform': translate,
    '-moz-transform': translate,
    'transform': translate
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {

  var lMouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
  var lMouseY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).height() / 2 - e.clientY));
  lFollowX = (20 * lMouseX) / 100; // 100 : 12 = lMouxeX : lFollow
  lFollowY = (10 * lMouseY) / 100;

});

moveBackground();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: #0F2044;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap .bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="bg">
    <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/fg.svg">
    <div class="bg">
      <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/mg.svg">
      <div class="bg">
        <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/bg.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I don't exactly know how the code is converted by the browser but I think we should not rely on invalid code.

It seems that this part

```
 <img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/fg.svg"
 </div>
```

is considered by the browser as  `<img class="front" src="https://shannels.com/fg.svg"</div>` (`<img .. >`) thus you will be missing a closing div and the browser will later try to close all of them.

This trick make the code easy to copy paste in order to add new layers but there is no guaranty that it will behave the same across all the broswers.

Comment: but how would i get the perspective to work without nesting??

Comment: @JakeS I think you need the nesting because of the scale effect, without nesting, you won't have the increasing scale of the element